# DLLs register present in a folder

Tags: batch-file, dllregistration

I have lots of dlls present inside a folder . I want to register all those dlls in a single shot by running one batch file , So that i dont have to register each and every dll one by one .
Please help me in generating a batch file for it .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this should work:

### Code:

```
@echo off
pushd C:\...[path to file]
for /r %%a in (*.dll) do (
Rem Put the instance of the REG command you want to use here
Rem (refer to file as %%a)
Rem e.g. | REG add %%a

Echo Registering %%a . . .
)
popd
Echo.
Pause | Echo Registration Complete: Program will now Exit
Exit
```

Pretty much `for /r` performs a recursive search through the current dir (and sub-dirs).

Type `for /?` for more info or ask if you want further explanation.

### Explanation:

In the above code all commands used followed by and explanation is below:

- `Echo` - Displays a message on the screen.
- `@echo` - Turns `Echo` to either on or off. Turning it off will suppress the console from displaying the prompt. That is, the user will not see what commands the batch file is executing, only what you tell the batch file to `Echo` and the output of any other commands used.
- `pushd` - Changes the current directory command prompt searches in to the path specified (and stores the previous direcotry for convienience)
- `popd` - Goes to the last directory in (in relation to `pushd`)
- `for /r` - Executes the commands specified for each file in the current and sub directory's where the variable created (in this example `%%a`) is the name of the file
- `Reg` - used to register
- `Rem` - Remarks in a batch file : These lines are comments that are ignored
- `Pause` - Waits for user input
- `Exit` - Exits

### Example:

```
@echo off
pushd c:\MyDll 
for /r %%a in (*.dll) do (
Reg /add %%a
Echo Registering %%a . . .
)
popd
Echo.
Pause | Echo Registration Complete: Program will now Exit
Exit
```

Comment: you have used very relative terms which i dont understand . Since i am new to all this .. can you please explain with an example .. 
E.g - All of my dlls are present inside c:\MyDll folder . Now just give me an example how can i register all those dlls present inside the given folder .